# Подскажите, как сделать пока i < 67, то i++, а потом было бы --i?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать пока `i < 67`, то `i++`, а потом было бы `--i`?

А если у меня такой код:

```
function swap_image() { 
  $("#main__welcome___block--first__animation").attr("src", "static/main_photo/"+i+".jpg"); 
  if(i < 67) { 
    i++ 
  } else if(i == 67) {
    i -- 
  } else { 
    i = 1; 
  } 
  initial = setTimeout("swap_image()", 60); 
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы сначала `i` увеличивалось от 0 до 67, а потом опять уменьшалось до нуля на каждом шаге цикла?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < 67; i++ ) {

}
i--;
alert( i );
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно завести переменную показывающую увеличиваем ли мы сейчас счетчик или нет.

Например:

```
function swap_image(min,max,dir, cur) { 
  $("#main__welcome___block--first__animation").attr("src", "static/main_photo/"+cur+".jpg"); 
  if(cur == min) { 
    dir = 1;
  } else if(cur == max){
    dir = -1;
  }
  initial = setTimeout(swap_image, 60, min,max,dir,cur+dir); 
}
```

Вызывать например так:

```
  initial = setTimeout(swap_image, 60, 0,67,1,0);
```