# Как сделать, чтобы сначала i увеличивалось, а потом опять уменьшалось на каждом шаге цикла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы сначала i увеличивалось от 0 до 67, а потом опять уменьшалось до нуля на каждом шаге цикла?

```
function swap_image(){
$("#main__welcome___block--first__animation").attr("src", "static/main_photo/"+i+".jpg");
if(i < 80) i++; else i = 1;
initial = setTimeout("swap_image()", 60);
}
```

Comment: у меня такое ощущение, что такой вопрос уже был

Comment: @Grundy http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505892

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var j=-67; j<=67;++j)
{
  var i = 67 - Math.abs(j);
  document.writeln(i);
}
```